# Comparing two data in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm fetching data from a **soccer live API** every minute using **AWS** for automation. I'd like to compare the new data with the old one. Each piece of data is an Array, so two JavaScript Arrays will be compared.

If there is a change in a new value, this value will be shown to the user at the Vue.js front-end. For example, the user will be alerted when shot on target rises to 4 from 3.

However, I'm struggling with that algorithm. Which **libraries or functions** will solve my problem?

Comment: How does the data structure look like? Is it always the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript?

Comment: @frhd yes same order elements.

Comment: @Pete thanks for answer but i would like to know which value that is changed. Of course, two array will also compare each other first then we have to know which value is changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more like you want to know the delta between two exactly same javascript structures. When I want to find out delta I generally use [deep-object-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff). It has multiple difference functions.

From the example from npmjs:

> ```
> const lhs = {
>   foo: {
>     bar: {
>       a: ['a', 'b'],
>       b: 2,
>       c: ['x', 'y'],
>       e: 100 // deleted
>     }
>   },
>   buzz: 'world'
> };
>
> const rhs = {
>   foo: {
>     bar: {
>       a: ['a'], // index 1 ('b')  deleted
>       b: 2, // unchanged
>       c: ['x', 'y', 'z'], // 'z' added
>       d: 'Hello, world!' // added
>     }
>   },
>   buzz: 'fizz' // updated
> };
>
> console.log(detailedDiff(lhs, rhs));
>
> /*
> {
>   added: {
>     foo: {
>       bar: {
>         c: {
>           '2': 'z'
>         },
>         d: 'Hello, world!'
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   deleted: {
>     foo: {
>       bar: {
>         a: {
>           '1': undefined
>         },
>         e: undefined
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   updated: {
>     buzz: 'fizz'
>   }
> }
> */
> ```

Comment: wow thanks for reply. I really didnt know that. I will inform you if i can do it or not.

Comment: reason for the downvote? Op asked `Which libraries` and I gave what I use